# Auth State Managment for Firebase in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I see that the Firebase documentation states that no user-auth information is stored during the login process. However, I have a few questions about how they handle that internally.

- Does the Firebase Android SDK keep the authentication state in memory? 
  If it does, what design or pattern is used for that purpose (singleton,      weakreferences, etc) ?
- Or does it execute a call to the server each time the ref.getAuth() method is called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the section of the documentation that describes [how to store such user data in your database](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing) yourself. It states:

> When you authenticate a user, no profile or user state is stored in your Firebase database.

Firebase Authentication is a separate service from the Firebase Database, even though they integrate nicely.

When you sign in a user with Firebase Authentication the Firebase client stores the resulting token in the app's `SharedPreferences`. This means that it survives application restarts (although it may expire while the app is not active).

The authentication state is also kept in memory. All `Firebase` objects share the same session behind the scenes, so there's only a single object between all of them. This also means that you can only have a single authenticated user amongst all `Firebase` references.

Calling `getAuth()` does not call back to the Firebase servers, which is why it's one of the few Firebase API calls that is synchronous.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!
However, one part of the question remains and is the one referring to how Firebase handles the memory and the object AuthData that lives inside the AuthManager.

For instance, when you use OkHttp or Picasso you can use a single instance of the object to avoid allocating and initializing all the handlers, objects and so on every time you use it. 

I ask this because I'm trying to design a part of the app and I need to know how Firebase authentication was designed to know the best way to plug it in my app.

Comment: I added more info on that. Note that this seems either a severe case of premature optimization, or a question that lacks concreteness on what you're worried about. Your own code is much more likely to cause problems than the Firebase SDK (although that can happen too of course).

Comment: Asking for information about how an SDK works is not premature optimization, It is just a question. "Your own code is much more likely to cause problems than the Firebase SDK" that is why I'm asking about memory management inside the SDK so I can build my code in a manner that wont break anything or cause problems. 

I'll state the question in a different way: Does the Firebase Android SDK keep the authentication state in RAM memory or does it change every time you create a new instance of the Firebase object?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply!